# Pandas calculate mean value every 30 minutes in an interval of +-10 minutes

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "observation_time": ["2021-11-24 10:10:03+00:00", "2021-11-24 10:20:02+00:00", "2021-11-24 10:30:03+00:00", "2021-11-24 10:40:02+00:00", "2021-11-24 10:50:02+00:00", "2021-11-24 11:00:05+00:00", "2021-11-24 11:10:03+00:00", "2021-11-24 11:20:02+00:00", "2021-11-24 11:30:03+00:00", "2021-11-24 11:40:02+00:00"], 
        "temp": [7.22, 7.33, 7.44, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.44, 7.61, 7.67, 7.78]
    }
)
```

```
           observation_time  temp
0 2021-11-24 10:10:03+00:00  7.22
1 2021-11-24 10:20:02+00:00  7.33
2 2021-11-24 10:30:03+00:00  7.44
3 2021-11-24 10:40:02+00:00  7.50
4 2021-11-24 10:50:02+00:00  7.50
5 2021-11-24 11:00:05+00:00  7.50
6 2021-11-24 11:10:03+00:00  7.44
7 2021-11-24 11:20:02+00:00  7.61
8 2021-11-24 11:30:03+00:00  7.67
9 2021-11-24 11:40:02+00:00  7.78
```

This dataframe is just an example, there is not guarantee the dataframe has point in time every 10 minutes, I could have data every minute or long period without.

I would like to calculate the mean value in an interval of +-10 minutes every 30 minutes starting from "00", in this case "10:00:00".

I was trying to use `Grouper`:

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="observation_time", freq="30Min", offset="0m", label="right")).mean()
```

This gives me this result:

```
                                temp
observation_time                   
2021-11-24 10:30:00+00:00  7.275000
2021-11-24 11:00:00+00:00  7.480000
2021-11-24 11:30:00+00:00  7.516667
2021-11-24 12:00:00+00:00  7.725000
```

which is fine from the time point of view, but of course it calculates the mean over the 30 minutes interval.

Instead I would like to calculate the mean in an interval of +-10 minutes.

For example for `2021-11-24 10:30:00+00:00` the mean is calculated among all the values of `temp` in the interval between `2021-11-24 10:20:00+00:00` and `2021-11-24 10:40:00+00:00`, which in this case are `7.33` and `7.44` and the mean is `7.385`.

The final result should be something like this:

```
                               temp
observation_time                   
2021-11-24 10:30:00+00:00  7.385
2021-11-24 11:00:00+00:00  7.5
2021-11-24 11:30:00+00:00  7.64
```

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: is the data in the DataFrame coming from a dictionary?

Comment: The data are in a CSV file and I read it with `pd.read_csv`, I edited the post adding it as a dictionary, maybe in this way it's more easy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**: the answer below worked under the assumption that each row corresponded to a 10 minute interval. If you have unevenly-spaced data, we have to manually bin the dataset to get the desired output:

```py
import numpy as np

# the sampling will be computed in +/- 10 minutes from the bin
sampling_interval = np.timedelta64(10, 'm')

# get 30 minutes bins
bins_interval = "30min"
bins = df['observation_time'].dt.floor(bins_interval).unique()

avg_values = []
for grouped_bin in bins:
    # subset the dataframe in the binned intervals
    subset = df[df['observation_time'].between(
        grouped_bin - sampling_interval, 
        grouped_bin + sampling_interval
    )]
    
    avg_values.append({
        'observation_time': grouped_bin,
        'temp': subset['temp'].mean()
    })

averaged_df = pd.DataFrame(avg_values)
```

---

I'm not sure this is the most "pythonic" way, but I would approach the problem like this:

```py
# we create an empty dictionary in which we'll store the computed avgs
# to turn into a DataFrame later
avg_values = []

# we iterate over the DataFrame starting at index 1 and skipping 3 rows at a time
for idx in range(1, len(df.index), 3):
    # store the observation time in a separate variable
    observation_time = df.loc[idx, 'observation_time']
    # compute the mean between the rows before the current one, the
    # current one, and the next one
    avg_in_interval = np.nanmean([
        df.loc[idx-1, 'temp'] if idx > 0 else np.nan,
        df.loc[idx, 'temp'],
        df.loc[idx+1, 'temp'] if idx < len(df.index)-1 else np.nan
    ])
    # we append the two variables to the dictionary
    avg_values.append({'observation_time': observation_time, 'temp': avg_in_interval})

# new DataFrame
averaged_df = pd.DataFrame(avg_values)
```

or, in a more compact and generic way, so you can configure the interval width of your averaging,

```py
interval_width = 3 # assuming it is an odd number
starting_idx = interval_width // 2
avg_values = []

for idx in range(starting_idx, len(df.index), interval_width):
    avg_values.append({
        'observation_time': df.loc[idx, 'observation_time'],
        'temp': np.mean(df.iloc[idx-starting_idx:idx+starting_idx]['temp'])
    })

averaged_df = pd.DataFrame(avg_values)
```

You can also turn it into a function to keep your code clean:

```py
def get_averaged_df(df, interval_width: int):
    if interval_width % 2 == 0:
        raise Error("interval_width must be an odd integer")

    starting_idx = interval_width // 2
    avg_values = []

    for idx in range(starting_idx, len(df.index), interval_width):
        avg_values.append({
            'observation_time': df.loc[idx, 'observation_time'],
            'temp': np.mean(df.iloc[idx-starting_idx:idx+starting_idx]['temp'])
        })

    return pd.DataFrame(avg_values)


averaged_df = get_averaged_df(df, 3)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer albjerto. Sorry I put a note in the post, there is not guarantee the dataframe has equidistant point in time, I could have data every minutes or never. If I understand correctly your code, it's based on the assumption there are data every 10 minutes. Sorry I wasn't clear in the original post

Comment: @cicciodevoto I updated my answer - check it out.

Comment: thanks, I like the idea of the bins. The for loop and append slow down the function, but I am working on that